# How do I get only the initial value of a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two variables 'oldAngle' and 'newAngle', they are basically the same variable but I want the first one to be only the initial angle (So it's value doesn't change) and the newAngle to always be the current angle so I can find the difference between them later.

```
float oldAngle = FindAng(v1, v2, v3);
float newAngle = FindAng(v1, v2, v3);
```

just like this, but I want the 'oldAngle' to only be set once, sorry if I didn't do a good job at explaining...

Comment: I can´t see why the value should change at all. As you´re doing the exact same thing twice any developer would immedialtely assume you get the same results.

Comment: I really feel like we're missing some code here. Where are these values stored and how are they used?

Comment: I want to compare them like this if (oldAngle > newAngle) { do smth } but they will always be the same and I don't want that, I want the oldAngle to be the initial angle and newAngle to be the angle that is updated every frame.

Comment: @Daka then split where/when you get them! Store the initial one e.g. in `Awake`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce the information to know `oldAngle` is initialized.

```cs
float oldAngle;
bool isInitialized = false;
...
if(!isInitialized)
{
    oldAngle = FindAng(v1, v2, v3);
    isInitialized = true;
}
```

In C#, we have nullable value type :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

```cs
float? oldAngle;
...
if(!oldAngle.HasValue)
    oldAngle = FindAng(v1, v2, v3);
float newAngle = FindAng(v1, v2, v3);

if(oldAngle.Value < newAngle)
{ ... }
```

Comment: float does not contain a definition for HasValue

Comment: But just checking if it's null seems to work fine, thanks.

Comment: but `float?` yes ;) See the link for more information.

Comment: nice it's working :)

Comment: @Daka Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear but from your comment

> I want to compare them like this `if (oldAngle > newAngle) { do smth }` but they will always be the same and I don't want that, I want the `oldAngle` to be the **initial** angle and `newAngle` to be the angle that is **updated every frame**

I guess what you're actually trying to achieve would be something like

```
private float oldAngle;
private float newAngle;

private void Start()
{
    // store initial value
    oldAngle = FindAngle(v1, v2, v3);
}

private void Update()
{
    // compare to current value
    newAngle = FindAngle(v1, v2, v3);
    if(oldAngle > newAngle)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Note that this highly depends on what `FindAngle` does and what `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are and how they are updated!**